# Parse SpeedTest-Cli Results to csv with awk

Tags: awk, sed

Hi how would I go about parsing the following results of `speedtest --simple` into a csv file:

```
Date: Wed 18 Dec 2019 08:01:09 PM EST
Ping: 28.394 ms
Download: 67.11 Mbit/s
Upload: 23.37 Mbit/s
Date: Wed 18 Dec 2019 08:30:01 PM EST
Ping: 38.813 ms
Download: 40.98 Mbit/s
Upload: 23.83 Mbit/s
Date: Wed 18 Dec 2019 09:00:01 PM EST
Ping: 83.865 ms
Download: 172.64 Mbit/s
Upload: 12.90 Mbit/s
```

I've been playing around with awk to do this but I don't have a ton of experience with it.

```
awk -v OFS=';' '/Date:/ /Download:/ { d=$2; } /Upload:/ { /Date:/, d, $2, ""; d="" }' speedtest.log
```

Comment: Why use awk? Speedtest-cli has a [--csv flag](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli#usage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just works for your data as follows:

```
awk -F': ' '/Date:/{printf $2} /Ping:/{printf ", "$2} /Download:/{printf ", "$2} /Upload:/{printf ", "$2"\n"}' speedtest.log > result.csv
```

The output (result.csv):

```
Wed 18 Dec 2019 08:01:09 PM EST, 28.394 ms, 67.11 Mbit/s, 23.37 Mbit/s
Wed 18 Dec 2019 08:30:01 PM EST, 38.813 ms, 40.98 Mbit/s, 23.83 Mbit/s
Wed 18 Dec 2019 09:00:01 PM EST, 83.865 ms, 172.64 Mbit/s, 12.9 Mbit/s
```

Basic knowledges:

- /pattern/{actions} means apply actions on the pattern matched lines, if you don't want some columns, just delete their corresponding /pattern/{actions}
- printf vs. print: printf will not print the \n ending
- -F': ' the seperator is comprised of an colon and a space, this will ensure the integrtity of the time text

You can use awk script to do more powerfull work, eg: let Date be always the first column, print a header line, etc. awk script file is more readable for complex processes.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't entirely clear what you are looking for, but I take from your question you want a 2-field .csv file from the input. With `awk` you can do that quite easily with using a regex of `": "` as the *Field Separator* (`awk` uses a single character or a regular expression as the field separator -- even though it is simply a string here, see: [Using Regular Expressions to Separate Fields](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Field-Splitting.html#Regexp-Field-Splitting)).

You want 2 fields, and since the `':'` isn't followed by a space in the time fields, you can simply use the first two fields to separate into your .csv, e.g.

```
awk -F": " '{printf "%s,%s\n",  $1, $2}' speedtest.log
```

**Example Output**

The results being there:

```
Date,Wed 18 Dec 2019 08:01:09 PM EST
Ping,28.394 ms
Download,67.11 Mbit/s
Upload,23.37 Mbit/s
Date,Wed 18 Dec 2019 08:30:01 PM EST
Ping,38.813 ms
Download,40.98 Mbit/s
Upload,23.83 Mbit/s
Date,Wed 18 Dec 2019 09:00:01 PM EST
Ping,83.865 ms
Download,172.64 Mbit/s
```

Let me know if this is the result you wanted, if not tell me how you wanted the different output and I'm happy to help further.